# Use wget to download files in url list

Tags: shell, wget

I am trying to use wget to download files within a list of urls.

For instance let's look at the following URLs which are contained within urls.txt: http://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0102/010292465
http://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0102/010272389

`wget -rkp --no-parent -R "index.html*" -e robots=off -i urls.txt`

In this case wget also downloads all files in http://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0102/, which I do not want.

Help would be appreciated..!

Answer (score -1):

```
## CLI BASH
## declare an array variable
declare -a arr=("index.html" "robots.txt" "img.png")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   wget "$i"
   # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

# You can access them using wget "${arr[0]}", "${arr[1]}" also
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not what I am looking for though. I want to download the files contained in both links (http://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0102/010292465 http://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0102/010272389). However whenever I specify wget -rkp --no-parent -R "index.html*" -e robots=off -I urls.txt, wget also ends up downloading the files in http://archive.stsci.edu/pub/kepler/lightcurves/0102/